# How to use const variables using C++17 std::any in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++17, constants

I prefer to pass on variables as constants and not use pointers in my code. There is a way around using pointers by employing std::any and overloading the -> operator as written on [this blog](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/01/29/inheritance-without-pointers/)

However I am not able to pass the resulting vector of arbitrary objects as a const variable, see attached code example. The code compiles using c++ -std=c++17 code.cpp and runs as it should, but if one uncomments the #define at line 49 the code does not compile anymore. Question is how should I change the definition of the BaseContainer to allow passing a vector of const object?

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>

// This code was inspired by:
// https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/01/29/inheritance-without-pointers/ 
// It requires C++17.

template<typename Base>
struct BaseContainer
{
public:
    template<typename ConcreteType>
    BaseContainer(ConcreteType&& object)
        : storage{std::forward<ConcreteType>(object)}
        , getter{ [](std::any &storage) -> Base& { return std::any_cast<ConcreteType&>(storage); } }
    {}
    
    Base *operator->() { return &getter(storage); }
    
private:
    std::any storage;
    Base& (*getter)(std::any&);
};

class Entry
{
public:
    Entry() {};
    
    Entry *self() { return this; }
    
    void print()
    {
        printf("2\n");
    }
};

class Inherited : public Entry
{
public:
    Inherited() {}
    
    void koko()
    {
        printf("3\n");
    }
};

// #define CONST
void printThem(
#ifdef CONST
               const
#endif
               std::vector<BaseContainer<Entry>> &entries)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (auto &e : entries)
    {
        e->print();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            auto f = static_cast<Inherited *>(e->self());
            f->koko();
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<BaseContainer<Entry>> entries;
    entries.push_back(Entry{});
    entries.push_back(Inherited{});
    printThem(entries);
}
```

Compile the code using

```
c++ --std=c++17 jkl.cpp
```

and run it using

```
./a.out
```

should give

```
2
2
3
```

Comment: Some hints: 1. you can use `emplace_back` to fill the vector. 2. const vector itself can't be modified once it created. 3. Probably you need a `std::reference_wrapper` for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't compile has to do with a C++ concept called "const correctness". A good overview is available [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). The idea behind it is that you can only call const-methods on const references and const pointers.
This is done in order to avoid mutating the internal state of the instance.
Methods which are const are still allowed, but the compiler will enforce that these methods don't modify the state of the object instance.

This is one of the core concepts and should be used throughout your code base. One thing you'll quickly notice once you embrace const correctness is that it tends to spread throughout your code (which is a good thing).

Here a solution to your example:

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename Base>
struct BaseContainer
{
public:
    template<typename ConcreteType>
    BaseContainer(ConcreteType&& object)
        : storage{std::forward<ConcreteType>(object)}
        , getter{ [](std::any &storage) -> Base& { return     std::any_cast<ConcreteType&>(storage); } }
        , getter_const{ [](const std::any &storage) -> Base const& { return std::any_cast<ConcreteType const&>(storage); } }
    {}

    Base *operator->() { return &getter(storage); }
    Base const*operator->() const { return &getter_const(storage); } // const correctness

private:
    std::any storage;
    Base& (*getter)(std::any&);
    Base const& (*getter_const)(const std::any&); // const getter accepting const reference
};

class Entry
{
public:
    Entry() {};

    Entry *self() { return this; }
    Entry const*self() const { return this; }
   
    void print() const // const correctness
    {
        printf("2\n");
    }
};

class Inherited : public Entry
{
public:
    Inherited() {}

    void koko() const
    {
        printf("3\n");
    }
};

void printThem(const std::vector<BaseContainer<Entry>> &entries)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (const auto &e : entries)
    {
        e->print();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            auto f = static_cast<Inherited const*>(e->self());     // added pointer to const
            f->koko();
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<BaseContainer<Entry>> entries;
    entries.push_back(Entry{});
    entries.push_back(Inherited{});
    printThem(entries);
}
```

I added comments where I made changes. Note that you can have overloads of methods which are const. The compiler will automatically select the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide `const` access to any of your objects.

First overloading `BaseContainer::operator->` to provide a `const Base *`.

```
template<typename Base>
struct BaseContainer
{
public:
    template<typename ConcreteType>
    BaseContainer(ConcreteType&& object)
        : storage{std::forward<ConcreteType>(object)}
        , getter{ [](std::any &storage) -> Base& { return std::any_cast<ConcreteType&>(storage); } }
        , const_getter{ [](const std::any &storage) -> const Base& { return std::any_cast<const ConcreteType&>(storage); } }
    {}
    
    const Base *operator->() const { return &const_getter(storage); }
    Base *operator->() { return &getter(storage); }
    
private:
    std::any storage;
    Base& (*getter)(std::any&);
    const Base& (*const_getter)(const std::any&);
};
```

Then also qualifying `Entry::print` and `Inherited::koko` to take "`const this`"

```
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry() {};
    
    const Entry *self() const { return this; }
    
    void print() const
    {
        printf("2\n");
    }
};

class Inherited : public Entry
{
public:
    Inherited() {}
    
    void koko() const
    {
        printf("3\n");
    }
};
```

And sprinkling more `const` as you refer to objects. [See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f0e3aa3f507b17b)